# Palabra o término para definir la existencia de dos cosas que existen a la vez pero que son completamente paralelas entre sí

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

¿Existe alguna palabra o término que pueda definir la existencia de dos cosas que existen a la vez pero que son completamente paralelas entre sí?

Aclaración: Es como si dos personas estuvieran realizando sus vidas en un mismo momento (tiempo) pero estas no chocan entre sí, nunca se conectan (espacio) porque no puede o no se debe. Otro ejemplo puede ser la existencia de dimensiones paralelas, donde las personas o seres de “x” dimensión realizan sus vidas independientes de las vidas de las personas o seres que puedan existir o no en otras dimensiones.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir. ¿A qué te refieres con que existan a la vez?

Comment: ¿Podrías dar algún ejemplo?

Comment: Es como si dos personas estuvieran realizando sus vidas en un mismo momento (tiempo) pero estas no chocan entre si, nunca se conectan (espacio) porque no  puede o no se debe.  Otro ejemplo puede ser la existencia de dimensiones paralelas, donde las personas o seres de “x” dimensión realizan sus vidas independientes de las vidas de las personas o seres que puedan existir o no en otras dimensiones

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es *simultaneidad dimensional*. No sé si es eso a lo que te refieres.

Comment: He oido hablar del universo paralelo, tal vez esa es tu idea?

Comment: He añadido tu comentario a la pregunta, porque me parece una buena aclaración para lo que estás intentando definir. Puedes editar la pregunta a tu gusto o dejarla como estaba si lo prefieres.

Comment: No sé si te refieres a la idea de *vidas paralelas* que se viene usando ya desde la antigua Grecia (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidas_paralelas). Esta expresión se sigue usando en la actualidad con frecuencia. Normalmente, cuando dos personas van haciendo cosas parecidas a lo largo de sus vidas, pero sin relación entre sí.

Answer (score 6):

Lo que buscas podría ser *simultaneidad dimensional* donde las cosas pueden existir en el mismo momento y lugar en distintas realidades o dimensiones.

En la entrada de Wikipedia sobre [universos paralelos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universos_paralelos) encontramos este párrafo:

> El principio de simultaneidad dimensional establece que dos o más
>   objetos físicos, realidades, percepciones y objetos no físicos pueden
>   coexistir en el mismo espacio-tiempo.

Si buscamos *simultaneidad dimensional* en [google books](https://www.google.es/search?hl=es&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=simultaneidad+dimensional&gws_rd=cr,ssl&dcr=0&ei=2mWuWciaNpDdwAKh17DIDg) hay varios libros que incluyen el término.

Answer (score 4):

Una pregunta interesante. Te pongo aquí mi propuesta:

> **Coexistencia paralela.**

Veamos el significado de cada palabra:

> **[coexistencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9eWqu3c)**
>
> 1. f. Existencia de una persona o de una cosa a la vez que otra u otras.

Esto cubre la primera parte de lo que quieres definir. Para la segunda parte podríamos aplicar figuradamente la definición geométrica de "paralela":

> **[paralelo, la](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rr2hl8R)**
>
> Del lat. *parallēlus*, y este del gr. *παράλληλος parállēlos*.
>
> 1. adj. Geom. Dicho de dos o más líneas o superficies: Que al ser equidistantes entre sí, por más que se prolonguen nunca pueden encontrarse.

Aunque esta definición se aplica únicamente en geometría, se podría extender al sustantivo al que está afectando este adjetivo, de forma que podríamos así definir existencias simultáneas (coexistencias) que nunca llegan a encontrarse.

Answer (score 1):

Puede parecer simple, pero yo usaría simplemente el término `independientes`

> Son independientes

Incluye el verbo "ser", por lo que en cierto modo al decir que son independientes, ante todo, "son", y por tanto existen. Además, lo hacen de forma independiente, es decir, que no interaccionan. Tambén puedes englobar este significado en el adverbio "independientemente", que puedes añadir a tus descripciones.

No sé si esto te sirve, es mi humilde intento.

Edito:
Posiblemente haya una buena retahíla de sinónimos entre los que alguno se ajuste mejor: emancipados, autónomos, indiferentes...

Answer (score 0):

¿Que tal la palabra *congruente/incongruente*? Su origen es matemático, pero puede aplicarse al concepto deseado, se dice que una figura es congruente cuando tiene la misma forma y se encuentra en otra ubicación.

Comment: Personalmente no entiendo cómo se puede aplicar el concepto de _congruente/incongruente_ al caso de la pregunta. ¿Podrías extender un poco más tu respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

hace referencia a dos entes -eventos, materia o disciplina- que no pueden existir independientemente. ejemplo: la pedagogía no puede existir sin la educación y viceversa... podría ser confluencia; que es la unión de dos cauces, refiriéndose a dos entes unidos. He percibido que algunos docentes lo utilizan en la facultad en la que estudio. sinceramente creo que hay otro termino pero no lo he podido encontrar... cuando lo encuentre intentare recordar actualizar este comentario. Saludos desde Veracruz
pd: espero no haber confundido su pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio! Yo pienso que *confluente* significa justo lo contrario de lo que se pregunta aquí: dos cosas *confluentes* son dos cosas que [confluyen](https://dle.rae.es/confluir), es decir, que se juntan. En esta pregunta, lo que se busca son dos cosas que nunca se juntan.

Comment: Aparte de esto, en Stack Exchange, nos resulta importante que las respuestas ("answers") realmente se enfoquen en responder a la pregunta, por lo que se espera que las respuestas no contengan elementos conversacionales como "saludos" o "gracias". Más información en el [help center](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help).